# How does Onavo Count know which app data originated from?

Tags: ios

Its common knowledge that Onavo Count uses VPN to redirect all internet traffic to their servers.
But how does the server* manage to determine which application the data originated from?

*I'm presuming it must be the server because there's no known way for the app to determine this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Onavo Count site](http://www.onavo.com/apps/iphone_count):

#### How it works

*Onavo Count monitors and analyzes all types of mobile data and phone use. This includes background, foreground, and Wi-Fi use. To keep your battery from being drained, Onavo Count directs all of your mobile network communications through their servers and measurement technology.*

So we can be sure that that data goes through their server. There can be few ways how to determine app one is `User-Agent` http header that contain relevant information about app and version, another way is ip addresses of destination host/port, is not always be determinative but in sum this can be >90% truth.

IMHO they can have more robust logic to inspect traffic but this information can be provided only by staff of company.